# new object with an void that modify textbox c#

Tags: c#, forms, object

Can you help me, please?
Its says that var. a is unassigned.
How should I declare it?
If i do not put "this" it says that is not a constuctor with no arguments.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person a,b,c= new Person (this);
        a.say("abc");
    }
}


public class Person
{
    public Form1 MyForm;

    public Person(Form1 form)
    {
        this.MyForm = form;
    }

    public void say(string w)
    {
        this.MyForm.chat.Text = this.MyForm.chat.Text+Environment.NewLine+w;
    }
}
```

So?

Comment: A `Person` class like that should have no knowledge of a `Form` like that.  It shouldn't be passed a form, it shouldn't be manipulating the form's internal controls, or anything like that.  You should separate your business logic from the UI.  `Person` sound like something that should be either storing data about a person, or manipulating data about a person, not displaying it to a form, that's a form's job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this:

```
Person a,b,c= new Person (this);
```

only actually initializes `c`. You need to explicitly initialize the other fields as well:

```
a = new Person(this);
b = new Person(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by creating three references to the same object? Simply assign the new `Person` object to `a`. You can assign the other variables afterwards.

```
Person a, b, c;
a = b = c = new Person (this);
```